# Tensorflow, encode variable length sentences by RNN, without padding

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I am dealing with a sentence modeling problem where I have variable length sentences as input. I want to encode sentences with and RNN (e.g. LSTM or GRU). All examples that I found use some sort of padding or bucketing for encoding the sentences to make sure all sentences in the batch are of same length. But I want to be able to dynamically unroll the lstm. 
Normally, I just define a LSTM cell and unroll it using `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn`.

```
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_units=64, state_is_tuple=True)
outputs, last_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
    cell=cell,
    sequence_length=X_lengths,
    inputs=X)
```

But, it seems that even the `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` expects the inputs to have the same length. Is there a way to handle variable length sentences without any padding in tensorflow?